# Is it possible to include a Bash script within a gem?

Tags: ruby, bash, rubygems

I'm creating a Ruby gem which I intend to publish on [rubygems](http://rubygems.org/). Unfortunately, there's one thing I can't achieve with Ruby and that needs to be done with Bash ([controlling RVM from script](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2551)).

Is it possible to include a Bash script within a gem and if yes, how would I run the script from Ruby in the context of a gem?

Comment: Have you tried : ./bin/mybash.sh ?

Comment: I don't really see what you mean, there. How would I include mybash.sh in the gem in the first place and how would the code within the gem call it?

Comment: just like passenger (here a ruby script (#!/usr/bin/env ruby) but should work with a bash (#!/usr/bin/bash) ) https://github.com/phusion/passenger/tree/master/bin

Comment: to call it, multiple options depending on your need ( backtick `mybash.sh`, system("mybash.sh"), IO.popen, Open3.popen3)

Comment: @majioa Running unix-like env only is fine. So, that means I can create a `script` directory within my gem tree, add a `myscript.sh`in it and from `myscript.rb` simply call `\`script/myscript.sh\``?

Comment: ...and most importantly, will `gem build mygem.gemspec` build and not complain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but the script can be executed only on unix-like environments, which include bash. You can put the **.sh** into `bin/` or `share/` folders, and just call:

```
name = 'your_gem_name'
g = Gem::Specification.find_by_name( name )
system( File.join( g.full_gem_path, 'share/myscript.sh' ) )
```

Of course, you always could use *bundler* gem module to control the current gems instead of running the shell script.